# how to show tier price with tax in magento 2 catalog listing page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

```
 <?php 
                        if($_product->getTierPrice()){
                            $tierPrice = $_product->getTierPrice();
                            foreach ($tierPrice as $key => $value) {
                                $qty = (int)$value['price_qty'];
                                $price = $value['price'];
                                $formattedTierPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);
                                $savePercentage = ceil(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $value['price']) ) ."%";
                                echo "Buy $qty for ".$formattedTierPrice." each and save ".$savePercentage."<br>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>**what we can add in this code for the show tier price with tax**
```

Comment: did you try this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208496/magento-2-get-product-price-including-tax

Comment: its not working can you tell me how we can call product tier price with tax

Comment: @zeshanrahman Have you got the solution i am also looking for the same solution, if yes please share the code.

Comment: sorry i didn't read your message let me know if you still need my help @Magento

Comment: @zeshanrahman yes I want your help to show tier price with tax in category list page